# How to make chating application in android?

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I want to create chating  app in which two different users able to do personal chating using app(like whats app), Here users registered on sql server.

Comment: @theDazzler thanks for this link but Is that any tutorial than send me link. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)(Google Cloud Messaging). Also, this question has been asked many times before so just use search.

Comment: Thanks Is that any tutorial than send me link!!